# elasticsearch match query is not working for numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search query which is used to search in report name. 
I have indexed the field name with autocomplete,edge_ngram
Normal field name search is proper when i'm having a number / year in the field name it's not working.
Query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "field_name": {
                  "query": "hybrid seeds india 2017",
                  "operator": "and"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Setting and the Mappings

```
{
"mappings": {
    "pages": {
        "properties": {     
            "report_name": {
                "fields": {
                    "autocomplete": {
                        "search_analyzer": "report_name_search",
                        "analyzer": "report_name_index",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "report_name": {
                        "index": "not_analyzed",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "multi_field"
            }               
        }
    }
},
"settings": {

    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "report_name_ngram": {
                "max_gram": 150,
                "min_gram": 2,
                "type": "edge_ngram"
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {               
            "report_name_index": {
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "report_name_ngram"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
            },
            "report_name_search": {
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can you guys help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you post your mapping, i'd be able to help.
try using the `_analyze` endpoint to check how your query is being analyzed by the analyzer configured with the field.

Comment: I have edited my post with the mappings and the settings.

Comment: and the field you are searching in is, "report_name.autocomplete" i assume?

Comment: seems to be working fine for me.
i indexed a document: "this is the year 2017" and can find it with and without the numbers.

Comment: Thanks @ArchitSaxena i would like to search mixed words in the same settings is it possible. ? Say for instance i need to search for the text "the year 2017" / "2017 is the year" both has to produce the same result. Is it  possible with the same settings. ?